# Declaring a C++ arraylist in Visual studio?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Apologies for the trivial question, but im having problems with the examples i find on microsoft support website.

Could someone please show me how to declare the libraries require (above main) for the ArrayList so that  i can just define it as such:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
```

I cant get the libraries for 'ArrayList' to be recognised?

Comment: are you using C++/CLI or native C++?  Add the appropriate tag (.net) if this is managed code.

Comment: Nobody here so far has noted that `ArrayList` is **deprecated**. Do not use it. If you want to use the CLI classes, use `System::Collections::Generic::List<T>` instead.

Comment: Barring some truly insane constructor signature, nothing is going to make that line of code compile.  The right-hand side is a pointer and the left-hand side is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using C++/CLI (managed C++)?  This class is not available in native C++, fyi.

[std::vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k449z507%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the closest native code equivalent.

If you are using C++/CLI then you have to add a reference to the required assembly (`System.Collections`) in your project - right click the project in Solution Explorer, select `Add Reference`, pick from `.Net` tab.

Then make it available to your code as shown below and in the MSDN examples:

```
using namespace System::Collections;
```

See [this one for Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(VS.71).aspx

You need this syntax:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections;

ArrayList* a = new ArrayList();
a->Add(S"One");
a->Add(S"Two");
```

Comment: I think this is old. Take a look at the example for .NET 4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @DaVinci, @Starkey - MSDN search is a bit rubbish as it randomly returns things from older version rather than favouring newest content.  Usually there is a dropdown for "Other Versions" to enable quick linking to newest.  Of course SO will then include stale links over time - *c'est la vie* ...

Answer (score 1):

in C++/CLI it is `ArrayList^ a = gcnew ArrayList()`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28VS.71%29.aspx) seems to indicate you need

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Collections;
```

Answer (score 0):

use stl's vector:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v_of_int;
   v_of_int.push_back(5);
   int val = v_of_int[0];
   ...
}
```

Comment: He asked for the necessary libraries to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList sounds suspiciously like a Java container - are you after std::list<> or std::vector<> maybe? Infact, std::deque<> will do you better!

Comment: Is sounds like a Java container, but it is also a managed C++ container. See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Evidently; but not all of us are windows developers, some answers take a standard C++ perspective, and given the original tagging (and even though the reference to msdn was there), we could be forgiven for answering with that perspective... ;)